# Is there an R function for finding a specific word on a website when web-scraping?

Tags: r, web, search, web-scraping, cpu-word

I am searching for the word "magnet" in `R` to see if some ISD websites have magnet schools and am using mat  What function(s) can I use to do this? I would then use `mapply()` to import multiple web pages instead of for-loop.

I've tried different web-scraping functions yet seem to get an output of error.

```
library(rvest)
    scraping_www.elkhartisd.org <- read_html (www.elkhart.org)
    scraping_www.elkhartisd.org %>%
```

I expect the output to be 1 if the word magnet is found on the website, but the actual output is an error.

Comment: You should use regular expression for that purpose. You can try functions in `stringr` package.

Comment: This is pretty unclear. What does "am using mat" mean? What's mat? What error are you getting? What's the code you're *actually* working with, since it trails off with a `%>%`, and unless you have a variable called `www.elkhart.org`, you probably are calling `read_html` on a string?

Comment: does R allow "." in variable names?

Comment: I do not have access to the website www.elkhart.org.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that can be considered :

```
library(stringr)
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet"
html_Content <- readLines(url)
unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(html_Content, pattern = "Magnet|magnet"))
```